# this is my error "name 'Rectangle' is not defined"

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, rectangles

here is my code? anyone has any idea where I went wrong?
I am trying to draw rectangle at different angles

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

X1Y1= (.2,.95)
X2Y2= (.4,.915)
X3Y3= (.6,.835)
X4Y4= (.8,.715)
w= .05
h= .15
angle1= -100
angle2= -110
angle3= -120
angle4= -130
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
rect = mpatches.Rectangle(X1Y1,w,h,angle1)
rect = mpatches.Rectangle(X2Y2,w,h,angle2)
rect = mpatches.Rectangle(X3Y3,w,h,angle3)
rect = mpatches.Rectangle(X4Y4,w,h,angle4)
ax = plt.gca()
# Add the patch to the Axes
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((X1Y1),w,h,angle1,color='red'))
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((X2Y2),w,h,angle2,color='blue'))
ax.add_patch(rectangle((X3Y3),w,h,angle3,color='blue'))
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((X4Y4),w,h,angle4,color='red'))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't know what `Rectangle` is. This should fix it:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
```

Or use `mpatches.Rectangle` as you did in the earlier block.

Note you also misspelt one as `rectangle`. Python is case sensitive.